# SSH IP address resolving

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ip

I just enabled ssh on my ubuntu pc. I had a doubt. Suppose I have two ubuntu PCs(say PC1 and PC2) configured as SSH server, both connected to the same router (lets say R1) through wifi. What will happen if I tried to connect to the public address of router R1 through ssh client from a third PC while both PCs have sshd up and running on the same port. Will I get connected to PC1 or PC2? How will ssh know where to forward the request?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/716190/1121748) your question?

Comment: Sorry, but no it doesn't answer my question, although I came to know about port forwarding where any unwanted traffic is redirected to a local IP address I think. So do I need to enable port forwarding in this case?

Comment: I think so. Otherwise, I think you're right, how would the router know where to send the ssh request? It wouldn't.

Comment: @wxz, exactly. So I researched more and found out that port forwarding is mandatory for connections from outside my local network and if I want to connect to any of the PC (PC1 or PC2) I would need to enable port forwarding. Reference [ssh port forward to access my home machine from anywhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19624/436327)